# Setting ListView ItemSource binding in code

Tags: wpf, listview, binding

I have a working ListView like this

```
<ListView Name="passageListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Passages, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" TargetUpdated="PassageListViewTargetUpdated">
```

where `Passages` is an `ObservableCollection<>`.

Now, how I do the same binding in code? (note that `NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True` has to be set)

I have tried to assign a `Binding` to `passageListView.ItemsSource` but this is not allowed and I can't use `SetBinding()` since `passageListView.ItemsSource`is not a `DependencyProperty`?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in the constructor of the control where the `ListView` is:

```
passageListView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, 
                new Binding
                      {
                          Path = new PropertyPath("Passages"),
                          NotifyOnTargetUpdated = true
                      });
```

If the DataContext is set properly, this should work.
The DependencyProperty could also be `ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty`, because that is the base class.